# How to catch "save" event & refresh filter form

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to refresh filter form after press save button, I ask

1. Which event catch save press? and
2. How to refresh Filter form?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Please provide more detail in your questions.  Context (explanation of what you are doing), Code, and Screenshots are important to get good answers.

Q - Which event catch save press?

A - The "event catch save form" is Persist.  There is an action equivalent as well, but generally you override Persist to add your changes.

```
#region PersistDelegate
public delegate void PersistDelegate();
[PXOverride]
public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
{
    // Insert code here if it needs if you may need to abort saving
    
    baseMethod();  // Executes the original Persist()
    
    // Insert code here if you need to do something after saving
}
#endregion
```

Q - How to refresh Filter form?

A - Too broad a question.  To point you in the right direction -> In some cases, this is a setting in the ASPX.  In some cases, you RequestRefresh in C#.  Find where Acumatica does something similar to whatever you are trying and then look to see if the ASPX or C# code contain the changes you need to make in your project.